How to Fix "TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string" when multiple optimizers are GridSearched for GaussianProcessRegressor?
Here is my script to predict targets on the final date of a timeseries dataset. I am trying to incorporate a GaussianProcessRegressor model to find the best hyperparameters using GridSearchCV: (Note that some of the code including most of the constants used are not explicitly shown in here to avoid clutter.)
HelperFunctions.py:
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=17, shuffle=True, random_state=4)


def randomized_search(
    model,
    distribution,
    X_train,
    X_validation,
    y_train,
    y_validation,
) -> None:
    try:
        randomized_search = RandomizedSearchCV(
            model,
            distribution,
            cv=skf,
            return_train_score=True,
            n_jobs=-1,
            scoring="neg_mean_squared_error",
            n_iter=100,
        )

        try:
            search = randomized_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

            print(
                "Best estimator:\n{} \
                \nBest parameters:\n{} \
                \nBest cross-validation score: {:.3f} \
                \nBest test score: {:.3f}\n\n".format(
                    search.best_estimator_,
                    search.best_params_,
                    -1 * search.best_score_,
                    -1 * search.score(X_validation, y_validation),
                )
            )

        except Exception:
            print("'randomized_search.fit' NOT successful!")
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            raise
        else:
            print("'randomized_search.fit' Successful!")

    except Exception:
        print("'randomized_search' NOT successful!")
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        raise

    else:
        print("'randomized_search' successful!")


def doRandomizedSearch(
    model,
    distribution,
    feat_train,
    feat_validation,
    tgt_train,
    tgt_validation,
):
    try:
        randomized_search(
            model,
            distribution,
            feat_train,
            feat_validation,
            tgt_train,
            tgt_validation,
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print("'doRandomizedSearch' NOT successful!")
        raise e
    else:
        print("'doRandomizedSearch' Successful!")


def model_randomized_search(
    model_dist_pairs, feat_train, feat_validation, tgt_train, tgt_validation
):
    for model, distribution in model_dist_pairs:
        doRandomizedSearch(
            model,
            distribution,
            feat_train,
            feat_validation,
            tgt_train,
            tgt_validation,
        )


class CustomOptimizers:
    def __init__(self, model, initial_theta, bounds):
        self.model = model
        self.initial_theta = initial_theta
        self.bounds = bounds

    def obj_func(self, theta, eval_gradient):
        if eval_gradient:
            ll, grad = self.model.log_marginal_likelihood(theta, True)
            return -ll, -grad
        else:
            return -self.model.log_marginal_likelihood(theta)

    def minimize_wrapper(self, theta, eval_gradient):
        return minimize(self.obj_func, theta, args=(eval_gradient), bounds=self.bounds)

    def least_squares_wrapper(self, theta, eval_gradient):
        return least_squares(
            self.obj_func, theta, args=(eval_gradient), bounds=self.bounds
        )

    def differential_evolution_wrapper(self, theta, eval_gradient):
        return differential_evolution(
            self.obj_func, theta, args=(eval_gradient), bounds=self.bounds
        )

    def basinhopping_wrapper(self, theta, eval_gradient):
        return basinhopping(
            self.obj_func, theta, args=(eval_gradient), bounds=self.bounds
        )

    def dual_annealing_wrapper(self, theta, eval_gradient):
        return dual_annealing(
            self.obj_func, theta, args=(eval_gradient), bounds=self.bounds
        )


class GPRWithCustomOptimizer(GaussianProcessRegressor):
    def __init__(
        self,
        optimizer="minimize",
        initial_theta=None,
        bounds=None,
        random_state=None,
        normalize_y=True,
        n_restarts_optimizer=0,
        copy_X_train=True,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        self.initial_theta = initial_theta
        self.bounds = bounds
        self.custom_optimizers = CustomOptimizers(self, self.initial_theta, self.bounds)
        self.optimizer_func = getattr(self.custom_optimizers, optimizer)
        super().__init__(
            optimizer=self.optimizer_func,
            random_state=random_state,
            normalize_y=normalize_y,
            n_restarts_optimizer=n_restarts_optimizer,
            copy_X_train=copy_X_train,
            **kwargs,
        )

    def fit(self, X, y):
        super().fit(X, y)


def intermediate_models(kernel):
    dtr_dic = dict(
        ccp_alpha=uniform(loc=0.0, scale=10.0),
        max_features=randint(low=1, high=100),
        max_depth=randint(low=1, high=100),
        criterion=["squared_error", "friedman_mse", "absolute_error", "poisson"],
    )
    optimizer_names = [
        "minimize_wrapper",
        "least_squares_wrapper",
        "differential_evolution_wrapper",
        "basinhopping_wrapper",
        "dual_annealing_wrapper",
    ]
    model_dist_pairs = []
    for optimizer_name in optimizer_names:
        gpr = GPRWithCustomOptimizer(kernel=kernel, optimizer=optimizer_name)

        gpr_dic = dict(
            optimizer=optimizer_names,
            n_restarts_optimizer=np.arange(0, 20 + 1),
            normalize_y=[False, True],
            copy_X_train=[True, False],
            random_state=np.arange(0, 10 + 1),
        )
        model_dist_pairs.append((gpr, gpr_dic))
    return [(DecisionTreeRegressor(), dtr_dic)] + model_dist_pairs


def cast2Float64(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    X_train_new = np.nan_to_num(X_train.astype(np.float64))
    y_train_new = np.nan_to_num(y_train.astype(np.float64))
    X_test_new = np.nan_to_num(X_test.astype(np.float64))
    y_test_new = np.nan_to_num(y_test.astype(np.float64))
    return [X_train_new, X_test_new, y_train_new, y_test_new]

utilities.py:
from HelperFunctions import (
    np,
    intermediate_models,
    model_randomized_search,
    cast2Float64,
)

def initializeKernel(median_distance, data_range):
    return ConstantKernel(constant_value_bounds=np.array([[1e-3, 1e3]])) * Matern(
        length_scale_bounds=np.array([[1e-3, 1e3]])
    ) + WhiteKernel(noise_level_bounds=np.array([[1e-3, 1e3]]))


####################################################################
def all_combined_product_cols(df):
    cols = list(df.columns)
    product_cols = []
    for length in range(1, len(cols) + 1):
        for combination in combinations(cols, r=length):
            combined_col = None
            for col in combination:
                if combined_col is None:
                    combined_col = df[col].copy()
                else:
                    combined_col *= df[col]
            combined_col.name = "_".join(combination)
            product_cols.append(combined_col)
    return pd.concat(product_cols, axis=1)


def ensureDataFrameHasName(y, dataframe_name):
    if not isinstance(y, pd.DataFrame):
        y = pd.DataFrame(y, name=dataframe_name, freq="C", weekmask=weekmask_string)
    else:
        y.name = dataframe_name
    return y.set_axis(pd.to_datetime(y.index)).asfreq(cfreq)

##################################################################################
def model_comparison(original_df):
    a = original_df["Result"].to_numpy()
    if (a[0] == a).all():
        original_df = original_df.drop(columns=["Result"])
    bet, train, features, target = """train_features_target(original_df)"""
    features_cols = [col for col in list(original_df.columns) if "Score" not in col]
    train.dropna(inplace=True)
    data = train.values
    n_features = len(features_cols)
    score_features = data[:, :n_features]
    score_target = data[:, n_features]
    feat_tgt_tuple = train_test_split(
        score_features,
        score_target,
        test_size=0.33,
        random_state=4,
    )
    feat_train, feat_validation, tgt_train, tgt_validation = feat_tgt_tuple
    data_range = np.ptp(feat_train, axis=0)
    distances = pdist(feat_train, metric="euclidean")
    median_distance = np.median(distances)
    values = list(feat_tgt_tuple)
    kernel = initializeKernel(median_distance, data_range)
    model_dist_pairs = intermediate_models(kernel)
    model_randomized_search(model_dist_pairs, *cast2Float64(*values))

score.py:
from utilities import model_comparison
###############################################################################
def main():
    # data_cls_with_result is basically some dataframe after processing.
    model_comparison(data_cls_with_result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

However, I am getting an error message that I cannot seem to fix:
'randomized_search.fit' NOT successful!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\username\Projects\Python\ScoreTest\HelperFunctions.py", line 38, in randomized_search
    search = randomized_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 812, in fit
    base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 75, in clone
    return estimator.__sklearn_clone__()
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 268, in __sklearn_clone__
    return _clone_parametrized(self)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 110, in _clone_parametrized
    new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
  File "c:\Users\username\Projects\Python\ScoreTest\HelperFunctions.py", line 158, in __init__   
    self.optimizer_func = getattr(self.custom_optimizers, optimizer)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string

'randomized_search' NOT successful!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\username\Projects\Python\ScoreTest\HelperFunctions.py", line 38, in randomized_search
    search = randomized_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 812, in fit
    base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 75, in clone
    return estimator.__sklearn_clone__()
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 268, in __sklearn_clone__
    return _clone_parametrized(self)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 110, in _clone_parametrized
    new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
  File "c:\Users\username\Projects\Python\ScoreTest\HelperFunctions.py", line 158, in __init__   
    self.optimizer_func = getattr(self.custom_optimizers, optimizer)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string

'doRandomizedSearch' NOT successful!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/username/Projects/Python/ScoreTest/score.py", line 483, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/username/Projects/Python/ScoreTest/score.py", line 479, in main
    model_comparison(data_cls_with_result)
  File "c:\Users\username\Projects\Python\ScoreTest\utilities.py", line 127, in model_comparison 
    model_randomized_search(model_dist_pairs, *cast2Float64(*values))
  File "c:\Users\username\Projects\Python\ScoreTest\HelperFunctions.py", line 96, in model_randomized_search
    doRandomizedSearch(
  File "c:\Users\username\Projects\Python\ScoreTest\HelperFunctions.py", line 87, in doRandomizedSearch
    raise e
  File "c:\Users\username\Projects\Python\ScoreTest\HelperFunctions.py", line 77, in doRandomizedSearch
    randomized_search(
  File "c:\Users\username\Projects\Python\ScoreTest\HelperFunctions.py", line 38, in randomized_search
    search = randomized_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 812, in fit
    base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 75, in clone
    return estimator.__sklearn_clone__()
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 268, in __sklearn_clone__
    return _clone_parametrized(self)
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\ts-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 110, in _clone_parametrized
    new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
  File "c:\Users\username\Projects\Python\ScoreTest\HelperFunctions.py", line 158, in __init__   
    self.optimizer_func = getattr(self.custom_optimizers, optimizer)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string


I suspect it's something to do with the sklearn API requirements around __init__ parameters and cloning (Guide section, but see the surrounding sections too), where your GPRWithCustomOptimizer doesn't explicitly set optimizer somehow means it isn't a string at some point and getattr fails. But I don't know where self.optimizer gets set, despite that being used a couple lines down...

If you could minimize your example ([mre]), it would be easier for others to reproduce and dig into.

@BenReiniger, this is my best attempt as I cannot share the actual data that get consumed by score.py.

Refactoring my code to create a minimal working example, I was able to catch the issue and resolve it according to the following new version:
#HelperFunctions.py
kf = KFold(n_splits=17, shuffle=True, random_state=4)


def grid_search(
    model,
    distribution,
    X_train,
    X_validation,
    y_train,
    y_validation,
) -> None:
    try:
        grid_search = GridSearchCV(
            model,
            distribution,
            cv=kf,
            return_train_score=True,
            n_jobs=-2,
            scoring="neg_mean_squared_error",
        )

        # Fit the model directly without using joblib
        search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

        print(
            "Best estimator:\n{} \
            \nBest parameters:\n{} \
            \nBest cross-validation score: {:.3f} \
            \nBest test score: {:.3f}\n\n".format(
                search.best_estimator_,
                search.best_params_,
                -1 * search.best_score_,
                -1 * search.score(X_validation, y_validation),
            )
        )

        # Delete large variables and collect garbage
        del X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation, search
        gc.collect()

    except Exception:
        print("'grid_search.fit' NOT successful!")
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        raise


def doGridSearch(
    model,
    distribution,
    feat_train,
    feat_validation,
    tgt_train,
    tgt_validation,
):
    try:
        grid_search(
            model,
            distribution,
            feat_train,
            feat_validation,
            tgt_train,
            tgt_validation,
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print("'doGridSearch' NOT successful!")
        raise e


def model_grid_search(
    model_dist_pairs, feat_train, feat_validation, tgt_train, tgt_validation
):
    for model, distribution in model_dist_pairs:
        doGridSearch(
            model,
            distribution,
            feat_train,
            feat_validation,
            tgt_train,
            tgt_validation,
        )


class CustomOptimizers:
    def __init__(self, model, initial_theta, bounds):
        self.model = model
        self.initial_theta = initial_theta
        self.bounds = bounds

    def obj_func(self, theta, eval_gradient):
        if eval_gradient:
            ll, grad = self.model.log_marginal_likelihood(theta, True)
            return -ll, -grad
        else:
            return -self.model.log_marginal_likelihood(theta)

    def minimize_wrapper(self):
        return minimize(self.obj_func, self.initial_theta, bounds=self.bounds)

    def least_squares_wrapper(self):
        return least_squares(self.obj_func, self.initial_theta, bounds=self.bounds)

    def differential_evolution_wrapper(self):
        return differential_evolution(self.obj_func, self.bounds)

    def basinhopping_wrapper(self):
        return basinhopping(self.obj_func, self.initial_theta, bounds=self.bounds)

    def dual_annealing_wrapper(self):
        return dual_annealing(self.obj_func, self.bounds)


class GPRWithCustomOptimizer(GaussianProcessRegressor):
    def __init__(
        self,
        optimizer=None,
        initial_theta=None,
        bounds=None,
        random_state=None,
        normalize_y=True,
        n_restarts_optimizer=0,
        copy_X_train=True,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        self.initial_theta = initial_theta
        self.bounds = bounds
        self.custom_optimizers = CustomOptimizers(None, self.initial_theta, self.bounds)
        self.optimizer_func = getattr(self.custom_optimizers, optimizer)

        super().__init__(
            optimizer=self.optimizer_func,
            random_state=random_state,
            normalize_y=normalize_y,
            n_restarts_optimizer=n_restarts_optimizer,
            copy_X_train=copy_X_train,
            **kwargs,
        )

    def fit(self, X, y):
        super().fit(X, y)
        # Delete large variables and collect garbage
        del X, y
        gc.collect()


def intermediate_models(kernel):
    dtr_dic = dict(
        ccp_alpha=np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, num=100),
        max_features=np.arange(1, 101),
        max_depth=np.arange(1, 101),
        criterion=["squared_error", "friedman_mse", "absolute_error", "poisson"],
    )
    optimizer_names = [
        "minimize_wrapper",
        "least_squares_wrapper",
        "differential_evolution_wrapper",
        "basinhopping_wrapper",
        "dual_annealing_wrapper",
    ]
    model_dist_pairs = []

    for optimizer_name in optimizer_names:
        gpr = GPRWithCustomOptimizer(kernel=kernel, optimizer=optimizer_name)

        gpr_dic = dict(
            optimizer=[optimizer_name],
            n_restarts_optimizer=np.arange(0, 20 + 1),
            normalize_y=[False, True],
            copy_X_train=[True, False],
            random_state=np.arange(0, 10 + 1),
        )
        model_dist_pairs.append((gpr, gpr_dic))
    return [(DecisionTreeRegressor(), dtr_dic)] + model_dist_pairs


def cast2Float64(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    X_train_new = np.nan_to_num(X_train.astype(np.float64))
    y_train_new = np.nan_to_num(y_train.astype(np.float64))
    X_test_new = np.nan_to_num(X_test.astype(np.float64))
    y_test_new = np.nan_to_num(y_test.astype(np.float64))
    return [X_train_new, X_test_new, y_train_new, y_test_new]

utilities.py
def initializeKernel(median_distance, data_range):
    return ConstantKernel(constant_value_bounds=np.array([[1e-3, 1e3]])) * Matern(
        length_scale_bounds=np.array([[1e-3, 1e3]])
    ) + WhiteKernel(noise_level_bounds=np.array([[1e-3, 1e3]]))


def all_combined_product_cols(df):
    cols = list(df.columns)
    product_cols = []
    for length in range(1, len(cols) + 1):
        for combination in combinations(cols, r=length):
            combined_col = None
            for col in combination:
                if combined_col is None:
                    combined_col = df[col].copy()
                else:
                    combined_col *= df[col]
            combined_col.name = "_".join(combination)
            product_cols.append(combined_col)
    return pd.concat(product_cols, axis=1)


def ensureDataFrameHasName(y, dataframe_name):
    if not isinstance(y, pd.DataFrame):
        y = pd.DataFrame(y, name=dataframe_name, freq="C", weekmask=weekmask_string)
    else:
        y.name = dataframe_name
    return y.set_axis(pd.to_datetime(y.index)).asfreq(cfreq)
##################################################################################
def model_comparison(original_df):
    a = original_df["Result"].to_numpy()
    if (a[0] == a).all():
        original_df = original_df.drop(columns=["Result"])
    bet, train, features, target = """train_features_target(original_df)"""
    features_cols = [col for col in list(original_df.columns) if "Score" not in col]
    train = train.dropna()
    data = train.values
    n_features = len(features_cols)
    score_features = data[:, :n_features]
    score_target = data[:, n_features]
    feat_tgt_tuple = train_test_split(
        score_features,
        score_target,
        test_size=0.33,
        random_state=4,
    )
    feat_train, feat_validation, tgt_train, tgt_validation = feat_tgt_tuple
    data_range = np.ptp(feat_train, axis=0)
    distances = pdist(feat_train, metric="euclidean")
    median_distance = np.median(distances)
    values = list(feat_tgt_tuple)
    kernel = initializeKernel(median_distance, data_range)
    model_dist_pairs = intermediate_models(kernel)
    model_grid_search(model_dist_pairs, *cast2Float64(*values))

UPDATE:
Here are the changes I made but I am not sure which one made it behave well or a combination of all!
1. Changing StratifiedKFold to KFold.
2. The n_iter parameter is removed as it’s not applicable to GridSearchCV.
3. The grid_search.fit method is called directly in the second version, whereas in the first version it is wrapped in a try-except block.
4. After the grid_search.fit method call, the second version deletes some large variables and calls the garbage collector to free up memory.
5. In the CustomOptimizers class, the theta parameter is removed from all the optimizer wrapper methods in the second version. Instead, self.initial_theta is used directly within these methods.
6. In the GPRWithCustomOptimizer class, the optimizer parameter of the __init__ method is set to None by default in the second version. 
7. After the fit method call, the second version deletes the input variables and calls the garbage collector.
8. The optimizer parameter of gpr_dic is set to a list containing only the current optimizer_name in the second version.


What was the issue?

I think item 3, 5, 6, and 8 mentioned above did the job but not exactly sure as it takes forever for my code to run.
